# Add To Crontab (if not already exists) Using Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

What is the correct way for a bash script to add a job to crontab, such that

- there will be no duplicate jobs
- the crontab file will not be resorted
- (optional) close to being a one-liner

Came across this solution below, but it does not affect the output of running `crontab -l`.

```
grep 'some_user python /mount/share/script.py' /etc/crontab || echo '*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py' >> /etc/crontab
```

Tried converting it to affect `crontab -l`,

```
(crontab -l | grep '/mount/share/script.py') || { crontab -l; '*/1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /root/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1'; } | crontab -
```

but running this command gives the error:

```
-bash: */1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /root/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but running this command gives the error:

```
-bash: */1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /root/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1: No such file or directory
```

---

The code:

```
(crontab -l | grep '/mount/share/script.py') || { crontab -l; '*/1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /root/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1'; } | crontab -
```

---

will try to execute/run the:

```
'*/1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /root/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1'
```

If and when `grep` failed.

---

Add an echo in front of it or printf, since `crontab` is expecting input from `stdin`, like what you did on your first example/code, something like:

```
(crontab -l | grep '/mount/share/script.py') || { crontab -l; echo '*/1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /root/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1'; } | crontab -
```

---

Here is an alternative, which is a full blown script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

is_in_cron='/mount/share/script.py'
cron_entry=$(crontab -l 2>&1) || exit
new_cron_entry='*/1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py >> /tmp/foo/logs/foo.cron.log 2>&1'

if [[ "$cron_entry" != *"$is_in_cron"* ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$cron_entry" "$new_cron_entry" | crontab -
fi
```